# Can not find symbol, unknown Identifier. How can I finish this?

Tags: java

Trying to get my Inheritance homework done and I have soo many error i am not sure where to start.

I am to create a Class called Horse that has a name, color and Date of Birth feild; with set and get methods. Then a subclass that is Race horse that adds number of races the horse has be in; also with Get and set method. Last an app that demos the using of each objects of each class. I am soo confused that i am unsure what I have even done.

I have a start

```
package horse;
```

public class Horse 
{

```
//Horse has 3 fields
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private int dob;   

public String setName()
{        
    return name;
}
public void setName(String nName)
{
    name = nName;
}
public String setColor()
{        
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String nColor)
{
    color = nColor;
}
public int setdob()
{        
    return dob;
}
public void setName(int nDob)
{
    dob = nDob;
}    

}
```

With done I made this

```
package horse;


import java.util.*;
public class Horse2 
{
String name;
String color;
int dob;

Horse aName = new Horse();
Horse aColor = new Horse();
Horse aDob = new Horse();
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
System.out.println("Enter name of horse");
name = keyboard.next();
aName.setName(name);
System.out.println("Enter color of horse");
color = keyboard.next();
aColor.setColor(color);
System.out.println("Please enter Date of Birth");
dob - keyboard.next();
aDob.setdob(dob);

}
```

This is new error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at horse.Horse.setdob(Horse.java:43)
    at horse.Horse2.main(Horse2.java:30)
C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)

Comment: Firstly, learn to indent your code. It makes it easier for you and others to read, particularly to visually identify the blocks where variable scopes begin and end.

Comment: Your code in the `Horse2` class is not in a method or initializer block.

Comment: no clue what you are saying

Comment: Try putting everything in between the `{` and `}` in `class Horse2` inside `public static void main(String[] args) { /* PUT STUFF HERE */ }`.

Comment: The top level of a `class {...}` is for declarations only, fields, methods. So `System.out.println(...);` does not belong there, place it in a ,method to be called, for instance in the mentioned main, that is the entry point of the application. Good luck

Comment: @AndyTurner  Thank you that did help

Comment: @JoopEggen I am very sorry, I am not sure what means. I am having a hard time think my son has been very sick, and I am caring for him and trying to get this done. So if you can talk like you explaining to a nube

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a class is as follows

```
public class Xxx {

    // <Field, Method, Constructor, Inner Class and Initializer Declarations>

    int n; // Field declaration of n.

    public static void main(String[] args) { // Method declaration of main.
       // <Statements>
       System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

You placed the System.out.println call immediately under the top level braces, where a declaration is expected.